# High risk probability

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I'm Stuck with this question. It is exercise no. 3.30 from the book "Probability  & Statistics for Computer Scientists" :

**Eric from Exercise 3.29 continues driving. After three years, he still has no traﬃc accidents. Now, what is the conditional probability that he is a high-risk driver?**

And Exercise 3.29 is:

**An insurance company divides its customers into 2 groups. Twenty percent of customers are in the high-risk group, and eighty percent are in the low-risk group. The high-risk customers make an average of 1 accident per year while the low-risk customers make an average of 0.1 accidents per year. Eric had no accidents last year. What is the probability that he is a high-risk driver?**

I have successfully solved 3.29 by Poisson Distribution and got the answer **0.09225**. But I can't figure out how to do 3.30 and what to do with that **"After three years"** phrase...
Please Explain like I'm 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly the same as the problem you've already solved, but instead of asking "what is the probability he is a high-risk driver given that he had no accidents last year?" we are asking "what is the probability he is a high-risk driver given that he had no accidents in the last four years?" (the year from 3.29 plus three further years of driving).

So instead of $P(\text{no accidents}\mid\text{high-risk})=P(\text{Poi}(1)=0)=e^{-1}$ for a one-year period, now we have $P(\text{no accidents}\mid\text{high-risk})=P(\text{Poi}(4)=0)=e^{-4}$ for a four-year period, and likewise the low-risk drivers have probability $e^{-0.4}$ instead of $e^{-0.1}$.

Comment: But that would change the parameter of poisson which shouldn't change...As I think?

Comment: But wait do you want to say that if the period of consideration changes, parameter also changes likewise?

Comment: Yes, if the number of accidents in a year is distributed $\text{Poi}(\lambda)$ then the number in four years is distributed $\text{Poi}(4\lambda)$. This is because of an important fact about Poisson variables that if $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* Poissons with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ then $X+Y$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda+\mu$.

Comment: Perfect....got it thanks :)